# How to sort strings as ints with lambdas in java 8

Tags: java, sorting, lambda

I have a List of objects each of which has a method getNumOrder that returns a string. The objects in the list are sorted in lexicographical order.
Most of the times all the objects in the list have getNumOrder that return an integer (but not always).

If all the elements in the lists have NumOrders that are integers I would like to sort them using integer sort order. Otherwise they will remain sorted lexicographically.

I have tried this using Java 8 Lambdas

```
try {
    results.sort((r1,r2)-> {
        Integer seq1= new Integer(r1.getNumOrder());
        Integer seq2= new Integer(r2.getNumOrder());
        seq1.compareTo(seq2);
    });
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // Do nothing: Defaults to lexicographical order.
}
```

There are 2 issues:

1. Because I dont know Lambda expressions very well the syntax is
   incorrect
2. I am not sure if this will work if the sorting by integer order
   fails, i.e. whether it will leave the list sorted lexicographically.

Comment: you have to return "seq1.compareTo(seq2);"

Comment: Use `Comparator.comparingInt(r -> Integer.parseInt(r.getNumOrder()))`.

Comment: @shmosel does that give an advantage over the .sort()-Method?

Comment: @watchme You would pass that to the `sort()` method. It's basically a shorter equivalent to Andreas' answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `new Integer(String)` to parse a number. It has been [deprecated in Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer-java.lang.String-). Use [`Integer.parseInt​(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) instead, or [`Integer.valueOf​(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) if you insists on boxing the value (a waste in this case).

The lambda you're after would be:

```
results.sort((r1,r2) -> Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(r1.getNumOrder()),
                                        Integer.parseInt(r2.getNumOrder())));
```

This leaves `results` unmodified if the sort fails, because the [`sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) method copies the list elements to an array, sorts the array, then copies the elements back.

If you prefer to store intermediate values in variables, e.g. so you can see them when debugging, you will be using a lambda *block* and it needs a `return` statement. That's what is missing in your code.

```
results.sort((r1,r2) -> {
        int i1 = Integer.parseInt(r1.getNumOrder());
        int i2 = Integer.parseInt(r2.getNumOrder());
        return Integer.compare(i1, i2);
});
```

---

*The below part of the answer was based on misunderstanding that input was list of strings, which it's not, so it doesn't apply to question, but I'm leaving it for others who might have similar problems where input is a list of strings.*

But it's not good performance. If strings don't have leading zeroes that need to be retained, it'd be better to parse to `int`, sort the `int` values, then format back to string.

Using streams (Java 8+):

```
results = results.stream()
                 .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
                 .sorted()
                 .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or this non-stream version (Java 1.2+):

```
int[] arr = new int[results.size()];
int i = 0;
for (String s : results)
    arr[i++] = Integer.parseInt(s);
Arrays.sort(arr);
results.clear();
for (int v : arr)
    results.add(Integer.toString(v));
```

Comment: What happens to this approach if the sort cant be done, i.e. if parseInt throws an exception?

Comment: @user2175783 All 3 versions fail, leaving the original list unmodified.

Comment: @Andreas +1 if you include the solution to his problem (the missing return statement) in order to include the information the OP wanted to know and those improvements.

Comment: @watchme OP is not asking for a solution to what OP tried, but for a solution to how to sort, and I gave 3 solutions that are all *better* than what OP tried to do. I see no reason to fix OPs attempt, which uses **deprecated** methods.

Comment: I think its good to know whats wrong with his method (the missing return statement), especially in the beginning of learning lambdas.

Comment: You don't have to include it... I just thought it would improve this answer for beginners.

Comment: @watchme And there are other useful answers covering that. Doesn't mean my answer isn't useful too, directing OP away from using deprecated methods, giving simpler solutions, and solutions that perform better.

Comment: @watchme You did say I should include it, as you said you only considered my answer useful if I included it (you said you withhold up-voting without it, and up-vote = useful). I disagree. My answer is very useful without it.

Comment: I believe a complete answer is significantly better than responding with performance improvements. Answering a question with performance improvements is like telling someone, that ask for directions somewhere, they just shouldn't go where they want to go. They ask, "How do I get to...?" To which you respond, "Don't go there, go here instead".

Comment: @Mikejg101 You missed the point. I didn't say "don't go there" because of performance, I said it because the code was using **deprecated** methods. "Deprecated" means "don't use for new code", and this is obviously "new code".

Comment: @Andreas fair enough. I think you have an almost complete answer. At the moment, this is more of a comment. My point was that you must answer the question first and then offer helpful hints. Just like everything else, you pseudo answer will become dated eventually as well. In the end, the answer that shows how to return is significantly more important than details on deprecation. Especially since it answers the specific question the OP asked.

Comment: @Mikejg101 I did answer the question: **How to sort**. That is the *main* question. OP then tried to do it one way, and sure, I have now updated my answer to cover the side-questions too, but I answered the *original* question, see question title ("How to sort strings as ints with lambdas") and question text ("I would like to sort them using integer sort order").

Comment: @Andreas Did you read the question or just answer the title? There are two questions (I should say 2 parts that must be covered) asked at the end. The first in regards to syntax and the second in regards to failure. You did answer the title. The question is whether your answer covers those. Did you answer the question in regards to lambda syntax?... no. Did the question in regards in regards to failure?... no. Did you answer the title?... yes. What's in a title besides grabbing our attention anyway?

Comment: @Andreas your update is great. This is an excellent answer now.

Comment: @Andreas As I said, you get the +1 ;-) I considered your answer always as useful!

Answer (score 2):

In order to make your code work, just return "seq1.compareTo(seq2);" like this:

```
try {
      results.sort((r1,r2)-> {
                        Integer seq1= new Integer(r1.getNumOrder());
                        Integer seq2= new Integer(r2.getNumOrder());
                        return seq1.compareTo(seq2);
                });
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // Do nothing: Defaults to lexicographical order.
}
```

As @Andreas pointed out in the comments, it shouldn't be done that way (with boxing and with using the constructor to parse a String to an integer), there is a cleaner and "not so wastful" way to accomplish that.
Here's the code:

```
try {
       results.sort((r1,r2)-> 
                     Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(r1.getNumOrder()),
                                     Integer.parseInt(r2.getNumOrder()))
                );
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // Do nothing: Defaults to lexicographical order.
}
```

Remember here that you only need to (explicitly) return a value in lambdas when you use brackets, as its then handled like a method which - in the case of "sort" - should return an Integer.

Comment: Boxing the integers is a waste.

Comment: If the list has 10 elements, one or more of which dont return an integer order will the sort fail globally and leave the original order unchanged or will it leave a partially ordered list?

Comment: @JennyToy If the sort fails, the list is left unchanged. This is because the `sort()` method copies the list elements to an array, sorts the array, then copies the elements back.

Comment: @Andreas indeed you're right. Nevertheless I thought its important to tell the OP whats wrong with his method of accomplishing that.

Comment: Excellently answered the question the OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot a "return" in your lambda :

```
return seq1.compareTo(seq2);
```

Other than that, seems fine, even if it fails

Comment: WHat is the difference between this answer and the answer of ["watchme"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49366939/1542723)?

Comment: approx 2 seconds in posting time I guess